# object sender is always null in RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

I am using RelayCommand to handle a button click, I need to get the sender parameter but it is always null, any idea why?

ViewModel.cs

```
    private RelayCommand _expandClickCommand;
    public ICommand ExpandClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_expandClickCommand == null)
            {
                _expandClickCommand = new RelayCommand(ExpandClickCommandExecute, ExpandClickCommandCanExecute);
            }
            return _expandClickCommand;
        }
    }

    public void ExpandClickCommandExecute(object sender)
    {
        //sender is always null when i get here! 
    }
    public bool ExpandClickCommandCanExecute(object sender)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

View.xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Expand" Command="{Binding DataContext.ExpandClickCommand,ElementName=SprintBacklog}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I need to get the index of the currect ListboxItem in ExpandClickCommand

Comment: Maybe the sender is not actually what I should be trying to get, I just need the index

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That object in all likelihood is *not* the sender but the `CommandParameter` that is passed by the control. You could bind the `CommandParameter` of the button to itself to immitate the `sender`.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

*(But that might not really help you that much, so think about what you pass in that helps you get that value.)*

Comment: Well I'm now getting something in the sender object but I cant seem to get the index, I changed that parameter to pass in the ListBox, but the CurrentItem property is always 0

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy: What `CurrentItem` property? ListBoxes have no such property. What exactly is your command doing? Can't you get away with a XAML-only solution?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy: Have you thought about using the `DataContext` (the current item) and getting the position from your data-list or is there some view on top of the collection so the list's `IndexOf` would produce wrong values? *(Even then you can probably manage to get your hands on that view and get the right index from it)*

Comment: sorry I meant SelectedItem. My xaml uses a List of objects in my viewmodel to populate its ListBox, I have a corresponding list of Visibility objects in my viewmodel, when I click the button I want to make some details hidden. So I want the index of the SelectedItem so I can update the correct item in the Visibility list  (its a messy solution I know, but I cant think of another way)

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy: Just use a dictionary instead, the key is the item, the value is the visibility, basically that's how dependency properties work as well. Using indices is messy indeed.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy: Or you could change your architecture a bit, create a viewmodel for each item, the viewmodel then contains the data-item and a visibility property and you have a list of those viewmodels.